# Could reopen review pages be more like close review pages?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

When I review a question for closing, the page presented contains a full reproduction of the question under consideration: title (which is a link to the original question), question body, and the all the comments.

When I review a question for reopening, all I get is the question body. That can be frustrating. I often need the full context of the question to decide how to vote on it. I am forced to search for the original question in the search box, which increases the time needed to perform the review.

I request that a least the title be provided to reopen reviewers. Better yet, I would like reopen reviews to be just like close reviews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the "Question (revised)" tab:

[image]

This'll give you the full question and title, just as you'd see it elsewhere in /review. The revision tab is selected by default because [folks thought it would be more useful to review what *changed* since closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231059/show-edit-summary-in-reopen-review/231943#231943).

I tend to agree that stripping *all* contextual information by default is not a good idea.

---

**Update:** Stripping all the contextual information is bad, so we've stopped doing that. The Revision tab now includes the question title and the same right sidebar with extra info that the Question (revised) tab does (number of answers, accepted answer or not, when asked, number of views, and a link to the full question).

[image: revision tab with context]